# Sharepoint 2013 With IE 11 - 401 UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: internet-explorer, authentication, sharepoint-2013

I have authentication problem when used IE to access my SharePoint site.
When I enter the address of the site, I don't receive any prompt to enter username and password and I get the error message "401 UNAUTHORIZED".
I have no such problem when using Firefox or Chrome.
I searched about this problem and a solution was changing authentication type in IIS from "Windows Authentication" to "Basic Authentication". This solution worked for me, but Basic Authentication is not secure and I don't want to use it. 
Is there any solution else to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try one more solution if it helps ?

To configure IE to prompt for credentials for Trusted sites:

Open Internet Explorer.
From the Tools menu, click Internet Options.
Select the Security tab.
Click the Trusted sites Web content zone.
Click the Custom level button.
From the list of settings, scroll to the end and select the button beside Prompt for user name and password.
Click OK.
Click OK to close the Internet Options window.

Let me know if this helps

Thanks

Comment: I examined this solution before, but this is not work for me.

Comment: Ok then can you check that you have proper permission as required. Add your self as a farm administrator or site collection administrator

Comment: The problem is the page does not prompt me to enter username and password!

Comment: did you delete the cache whole cache with the save username and password ?

Comment: I tried again, and the page prompt me to enter the username and password and I checked the case that saying save my credential and then it is work!!! If I don't check this option, I get the unauthorized error message. Isn't it a bug for IE?

Comment: I am not sure for that.. if my solution helped you then please mark it as an answer.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had a similar problem with the Authorization mechanism in "MS IE 11" - I did constantly receive the same error message "401 Authorization Required" although I have earlier pasted valid user name and password for several times (3 times in each cycle). I have also **clicked** to check the option "Save my credential" and "OK" button to log on. It was very frustrating. Just like Gohar I had no problems while logging in with other browsers ("Firefox", "Opera" or even older versions of "MS Internet Explorer" including version 6.0!).

And then with my N-th try just by accident I have **manually (with keyboard)** entered everything (without mouse clicking anything) and it finally worked!

It seams that "Microsoft Internet Explorer 11" (64-bit on "Windows 7") is a bit buggy. After several other tests I can tell you now that there was no problem with copying and pasting of login and password to the standard authorization form (with right mouse button and context menu) nor with clicking the "OK" button. In my case the solution to the problem was **switching between fields** in the standard "MS IE 11" window form **with the Tab** key.

It's just that simple... and yet very frustrating. I hope it helps anyone.